# for and foreach statements in D

Tags: d

Besides the syntactic differences, are the two inherently the same?  Are both of them implemented in the core language? or is `foreach` part of the standard library?  And as far as performance, does it make a difference if I choose one over the other?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should always use `foreach` if possible.

1. `foreach` iterate over practically *anything* (even metadata, like compile-time data types); `for` can't.

   ```
   foreach (Type; TypeTuple!(int, long, short)) { pragma(msg, Type); }
   ```

   but you can't do that with a `for` loop.
2. `foreach` can be used to perform actions at compile-time (extension of above); for example, if you have a piece of code that repeats 10 times, you can say:

   ```
   template Iota(size_t a, size_t b) //All integers in the range [a, b)
   {
       static if (a < b) { alias TypeTuple!(a, Iota!(a + 1, b)) Iota; }
       else { alias TypeTuple!() Iota; }
   }

   foreach (i; Iota!(0, 10)) { int[i] arr; } //Not possible with 'for'
   ```

   and this will **occur at compile-time**, with `i` treated as a **constant**. (This doesn't normally work with `for`.)
3. `foreach` can be overloaded with `opApply` and also with range constructs, but `for` can't. This is **very handy** when iterating a tree structure (like all the folders in a file system), because it actually allows you to use *entirely stack-based memory* rather than allocating on the heap (because you can use recursion).
4. `foreach` is preferred in most situations because it prevents the need for you to type your data explicitly, which is useful in preventing some bugs. For example,

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { arr[i]++; }
   ```

   is dangerous if `n` is greater than 2^32 - 1, but

   ```
   foreach (i; 0 .. n) { arr[i]++; }
   ```

   is not, because the compiler automatically chooses the correct type for iteration. This also improves readability.

Comment: Do you know how `foreach` is lowered for arrays which are not ranges? How can I access the array-iterator explicitly? Sorry for asking in a comment. I think, this is related to this OP.

Comment: Hm, I started to read the chapter about ranges from Ali Çehreli's book and where he pointed out that iteration over an array can be done by reducing slices in length, I noticed, that slicing a fixed-size array turns it into an iterator which is compatible to ranges. Using `array[0..$]` is the simplest way to get a range-compatible "iterator" over fixed-size arrays (but watch out not to delete elements from it which would result into a GC-allocated copy which breaks sharing of elements between slice and array).

Answer (score 10):

The main difference between `foreach` and `for` is the higher level of 
abstraction of a `foreach`-loop. A `foreach`-loop is typically lowered to some 
`for`-loop by the compiler. This has (at least) four advantages:

1. **Readability**: `foreach (a; someArray) doSomething(a);` is inherently more 
   readable than `for (size_t i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) doSomething(someArray[i]);`.
   This gets even clearer if the type of `someArray` is not a simple array.
2. **Flexibility**: if, at one point in time, you decide that the type of 
   `someArray` has to be changed from some array to, say, a range or an object 
   (e.g. to implement a parallel loop), `foreach` stays unchanged whereas the 
   `for`-loop has to be changed to use either `empty`, `front` and `popFront` 
   (in the case of a range) or `opApply` or some other mechanism in the case of a 
   class or struct.
3. **Special features**, e.g. iterating over type tuples, decoding of UTF-8 and 
   UTF-16 strings.
4. **Performance**: the `foreach`-loop lets the compiler decide how to optimally 
   implement the loop based on the type (iterating over an array, a range, 
   a string, an object ...) and possibly other information (e.g. the size of the 
   type). This allows for efficient implementation for all types and other compiler 
   optimizations without you having to worry too much about implementation 
   details. In reality, the performance of `foreach` relative to hand-coded `for` 
   is mixed. `foreach(dchar c; someString) {...}` (i.e. the decoding of an UTF-8 
   string while looping) is very fast. But `foreach(a; someObject) {...}`, where 
   `someObject` implements `opApply`, is a tad slower (because the loop body is 
   wrapped into a delegate and opApply typically calls this delegate inside a loop, which 
   generates some overhead). As usual, this won't matter to your code in 99.99% of
   the cases, as `foreach` will always yield an (at least) decent implementation.

The main disadvantage (besides, occasionally, speed) is that some things cannot 
be done with `foreach`, namely many mutations of the thing being looped over 
(e.g. resizing of an array within the loop body).